# GuidedAction setEnable won't change the text color

Tags: android, leanback

I'm developing an Android TV application which is using Leanback library. There is a login form with email, password and a login button. I'd like to enable the login button only when the email and password are valid.

Here is my code:

```
mLoginButtonAction = new GuidedAction.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .id(id)
            .title(title)
            .description(desc)
            .build();
actions.add(action);
```

I disable it at first:

```
mLoginButtonAction.setEnabled(false);
```

And then enable it when it's valid:

```
mLoginButtonAction.setEnabled(valid);
```

The button is then enabled and I'm able to click it. But the color of the button is still the same color as in disable mode. Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can I have your email address?

Answer (score 5):

Modification to actions do not trigger notifications to the GuidedStepFragment and must be done so manually.

To notify an action change you first need the items index.

```
int idx = findActionPositionById(actionId);
```

Get and modify your action

```
GuidedAction someAction = getActions().get(idx);
someAction.setEnabled(valid);
```

Next notify the fragment of the update

```
notifyActionChanged(idx);
```